# Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following code in my SwiftUI app:

```
protocol ButtonState: CaseIterable {
    var title: String { get }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedState: ButtonState?
```

The line @State private var selectedState: ButtonState? is causing issues and giving the following error:

```
Protocol 'ButtonState' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: CaseIterable has an associated type (AllCases). You cannot require it in an existential (i.e. the type of a property). Get rid of the CaseIterable requirement and this should be fine.

Comment: I need to make sure that enum cases are enumeratable. That is the reason for CaseIterable.

Answer (score 0):

Rob's comment is one way to go about it, but it's better to not use existentials.

```swift
struct ContentView<SelectedState: ButtonState> {
  @State private var selectedState: SelectedState?
```